# Unable to upgrade 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: upgrade

trying to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 and getting error:

"Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If you want to investigate this yourself the log files in '/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'."

I ran the below, and there are some broken packages, I don't know if it's safe to remove these though?

Please let me know if you have suggestions.  Thank you!

Output of /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log

```
  Considering gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Considering gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 < 1.450.2 | 1.481 @ii umR >
  Considering ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Considering ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-session:amd64 < 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 | 42.0-1ubuntu2 @ii umR >
  Considering ubuntu-session:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Considering ubuntu-session:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
Done
Log time: 2022-09-10 17:03:23.064029
```

Comment: googling the error says it might be due to LTS, are you on LTS? and are you upgrading to LTS?

Comment: Please edit your question and use complete information. For example *"I ran the below, and there are some broken packages"* -- We should not have to guess what this means. This is probably important but we have no way of knowing without knowing exactly what it says.  Your system must be up-to-date with no broken packages to release upgrade. Please tell us the commands you are using and post the whole output of each command. Do not summarize in your own words. Please format terminal output as monospace using code fences just like you did with your logs.

Comment: Check `/etc/apt/preferences.d` for additional info (and update your question). Any additional repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` ?